# Does 40% Less Damage affect Conversion Trap using Multiple Traps?

Tags: path-of-exile

What I mean is that Multiple Traps has this 40% Less Damage effect. So when using it with Conversion Traps on mobs, does that mean that this 40% Less Damage apply to mobs damage? They start hitting others with 40% Less Damage or does this apply only for spell traps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion Trap works with Trap Supports.

With Multiple Traps, the monsters will do 40% Less Damage than usual.

In contrast, physical-based or anything that adds elemental damage makes it so converted monsters do more damage.